# difference between $('.mydiv').children().last() and $('.mydiv').last()

Tags: jquery

Is there any difference between :

```
$('.mydiv').children().last()
```

and

```
$('.mydiv').last()?
```

Which one is better to be used when we want to get the last children inside a div for example?

Comment: `the last children inside a div` If only one `div`, the 'best' would be `$('.mydiv > :last-child')`

Comment: @A.Wolff - NO, `$('.mydiv').children().last()` is better due to the right to left processing of the Sizzle engine.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Ya but on modern browser, it won't use sizzle but `querySelectorAll()`, `'.mydiv > :last-child'` beeing a valid CSS selector

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
$('.mydiv').children().last()
```

as `$('.mydiv').last()` will not provide any children

Answer (score 0):

Just like it sounds.

`$('.mydiv').children().last()` selects the children of the `.mydiv` elements and then take the last item from that children list.

and `$('.mydiv').last()` selects all the `.mydiv` elements and then get the last on from the list.

If you have multiple `$('.mydiv')` elements, then `$('.mydiv').children().last()` will get you the last child of the last `$('.mydiv')`. If you need to get last child of a specific `$('.mydiv')` div, then you can use `first()` or `last()` or `eq(index)` to get the pecific item and then get the last child.

```
//this select the second .myDiv then get its children and then the last of those children
$('.mydiv').eq(1).children().last();
```

Answer (score 0):

With `$('.mydiv').children().last()` you are referencing last child of `.mydiv`, and with `$('.mydiv').last()` you will refer to last element of `$('.mydiv')` element collection

Answer (score 0):

That's way too different , `.children().last()` selects last children of respective div .

while `.last()` select the last div of that type , in your example last div with class mydiv.

Here is an example HTML to play with

```js
//first one is commented. 

//$( "ul.level-2" ).children().last().css( "background-color", "red" );

$( "ul.level-2" ).last().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level-1">
      <li class="item-i">I</li>
      <li class="item-ii">II
        <ul class="level-2">
          <li class="item-a">A</li>
          <li class="item-b">B
            <ul class="level-3">
              <li class="item-1">1</li>
              <li class="item-2">2</li>
              <li class="item-3">3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="item-c">C</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

..............................................................................

JQUERY FOR ABOVE HTML :

..............................................................................

```
$( "ul.level-2" ).last().css( "background-color", "red" );

$( "ul.level-2" ).children().last().css( "background-color", "red" );
```